# want to show controller message on jsp page in alertbox

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("student") Student s, Model model) {

        boolean isRegistered = sptiService.add(s);
        if (isRegistered == true)
            model.addAttribute("msg", "You have registered");
        else
            model.addAttribute("msg", "Unable to register");
        return "home";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set the msg value in hidden input.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head></head>
 <title></title>
 <body>
 <input type="hidden" value="${msg}" id="hiddenId">

 <script type="text/javascript">
      alert($("#hiddenId").val());
 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```